# AWS step-function mapState iterate over large payloads

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, aws-step-functions

I have a state-machine consisting of a first pre-process task that generates an array as output, which is used by a subsequent map state to loop over. The output array of the first task has gotten too big and the state-machine throws the error `States.DataLimitExceeded`: `The state/task 'arn:aws:lambda:XYZ' returned a result with a size exceeding the maximum number of characters service limit.`

Here is an example of the state-machine yaml:

```or-tag-here
stateMachines:
  myStateMachine:
    name: "myStateMachine"
    definition:
      StartAt: preProcess
      States:
        preProcess:
          Type: Task
          Resource:
            Fn::GetAtt: [preProcessLambda, Arn]
          Next: mapState
          ResultPath: "$.preProcessOutput"
        mapState:
          Type: Map
          ItemsPath: "$.preProcessOutput.data"
          MaxConcurrency: 100
          Iterator:
            StartAt: doMap
            States:
              doMap:
                Type: Task
                Resource:
                  Fn::GetAtt: [doMapLambda, Arn]
                End: true
          Next: ### next steps, not relevant
```

A possible solution I came up with would be that state `preProcess` saves its output in an S3-bucket and state `mapState` reads directly from it. Is this possible? At the moment the output of `preProcess` is

`ResultPath: "$.preProcessOutput"`

and `mapState` takes the array

`ItemsPath: "$.preProcessOutput.data"`
as input.

How would I need to adapt the yaml that the map state reads directly from S3?

Comment: Did you come up with a solution? I'm facing this too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am solving a similar problem at work currently too. Because a step function stores its entire state, you can pretty quickly have problems as your json grows as it maps over all the values.

The only real way to solve this is to use hierarchies of step functions. That is, step functions on your step functions. So you have:

`parent -> [batch1, batch2, batch...N]`

And then each batch have a number of single jobs:

`batch1 -> [j1,j2,j3...jBATCHSIZE]`

I had a pretty simple step function, and I found at `~4k` was about the max batch size I could have before I would start hitting state limits.

Not a pretty solution be hey it works.

Comment: the problem here is when there is one step a normal parent and produce many short elements, I don' see a way stream out many outputs from a single step. And If I put the many elements in S3 how would the Map iterator be aware of that ?

Comment: You can’t directly go to a map iterator from s3. You would first have a lambda which reads from s3 and then creates your batches/stepfuncs . The json input to each batch will rather be a subset of the elements in the array from the previous step. Or the start and end index of the array if state is too large. You might find that an ETL tool would be better suited as well just depends on all the details.

Comment: That way you need to return at least the list of bucket keys, what if the bucket list is too large ? Returning the index is also problematic, because each execution would need to load the whole list and make the slice.

Comment: That’s a good point, you would have to save the array in partitions, i.e. in 1k element batches. If you couldn’t change this behaviour you can also get byte ranges of an s3 item but I would think that is a pain.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to read directly from S3 at this time. There are a few things you could try to do to get around this limitation. One is making your own iterator and not using Map State. Another is the following:

Have a lambda read your s3 file and chunk it by index or some id/key. The idea behind this step is to pass the iterator in Map State a WAY smaller payload. Say your data has the below structure.

`[ { idx: 1, ...more keys }, {idx: 2, ...more keys }, { idx: 3, ...more keys }, ... 4,997 more objects of data ]`

Say you want your iterator to process 1,000 rows at a time. Return the following tuples representing indexs from your lambda instead: `[ [ 0, 999 ], [ 1000, 1999 ], [ 2000, 2999 ], [ 3000, 3999 ], [ 4000, 4999] ]`

Your Map State will receive this new data structure and each iteration will be one of the tuples. Iteration #1: [ 0, 999 ], Iteration #2: [ 1000, 1999 ], etc

Inside your iterator, call a lambda which uses the tuple indexes to query into your S3 file. AWS has a query language over S3 buckets called `Amazon S3 Select`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-select.html

Here’s another great resource on how to use S3 select and get the data into a readable state with node: https://thetrevorharmon.com/blog/how-to-use-s3-select-to-query-json-in-node-js

So, for iteration #1, we are querying the first 1,000 objects in our data structure. I can now call whatever function I normally would have inside my iterator.

What's key about this approach is the inputPath is never receiving a large data structure.

Comment: Not that the (`SelectObjectContent`) is listed in the unsupported API actions for supported integrations (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/supported-services-awssdk.html#unsupported-api-actions-list). That means that S3-Select would not add all the result records to the workflow. And if you query that from a lambda  function then the big list of results might exceed the payload limit. Something is needed for the lambda function to stream many outputs from one execution.

Answer (score 1):

As of September 2020 the limit on step functions has been increased 8-fold

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/09/aws-step-functions-increases-payload-size-to-256kb/

Maybe now it fits within your requirements

Comment: Following your link I see that they recognize the limitation, also propose the model of Dynamic Parallelism to mitigate the problem (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-larger-state-payloads-for-aws-step-functions/). Nevertheless it is not clear to overcome the limitation if the output of one step like "Retrieve Items" is a long list of items  that exceed the limit and the next Map step iterates over the list.

Answer (score 1):

Just writing this in case someone else comes across the issue - I recently had to solve this at work as well. I found what I thought to be a relatively simple solution, without the use of a second step function.

I'm using Python for this and will provide a few examples in Python, but the solution should be applicable to any language.

Assuming the pre-process output looks like so:

```
[
    {Output_1},
    {Output_2},
    .
    .
    .
    {Output_n}
]
```

And a simplified version of the section of the Step Function is defined as follows:

```
"PreProcess": {
    "Type": "Task",
    "Resource": "Your Resource ARN",
    "Next": "Map State"
},
"Map State": {
    Do a bunch of stuff
}
```

To handle the scenario where the PreProcess output exceeds the Step Functions payload:

1. Inside the PreProcess, batch the output into chunks small enough to not exceed the payload.

   This is the most complicated step. You will need to do some experimenting to find the largest size of a single batch. Once you have the number (it may be smart to make this number dynamic), I used numpy to split the original PreProcess output into the number of batches.

   ```
   import numpy as np
   batches = np.array_split(original_pre_process_output, number_of_batches)
   ```
2. Again inside the PreProcess, upload each batch to Amazon S3, saving the keys in a new list. This list of S3 keys will be the new PreProcess output.

   In Python, this looks like so:

   ```
   import json
   import boto3

   s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

   batch_keys = []
   for batch in batches:
       s3_batch_key = 'Your S3 Key here'
       s3.Bucket(YOUR_BUCKET).put_object(Key=s3_batch_key, Body=json.dumps(batch))
       batch_keys.append({'batch_key': s3_batch_key})
   ```

   In the solution I implemented, I used `for batch_id, batch in enumerate(batches)` to easily give each S3 key its own ID.
3. Wrap the 'Inner' Map State in an 'Outer' Map State, and create a Lambda function within the Outer Map to feed the batches to the Inner Map.

   Now that we have a small output consisting of S3 keys, we need a way to open one at a time, feeding each batch into the original (now 'Inner') Map state.

   To do this, first create a new Lambda function - this will represent the `BatchJobs` state. Next, wrap the initial Map state inside an Outer map, like so:

   ```
   "PreProcess": {
   "Type": "Task",
   "Resource": "Your Resource ARN",
   "Next": "Outer Map"
   },
   "Outer Map": {
       "Type": "Map",
       "MaxConcurrency": 1,
       "Next": "Original 'Next' used in the Inner map",
       "Iterator": {
           "StartAt": "BatchJobs",
           "States": {
               "BatchJobs": {
                   "Type": "Task",
                   "Resource": "Newly created Lambda Function ARN",
                   "Next": "Inner Map"   
               },
               "Inner Map": {
                    Initial Map State, left as is.
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Note the 'MaxConcurrency' parameter in the Outer Map - This simply ensures the batches are executed sequentially.

   With this new Step Function definition, the `BatchJobs` state will receive `{'batch_key': s3_batch_key}`, for each batch. The `BatchJobs` state then simply needs to get the object stored in the key, and pass it to the Inner Map.

   In Python, the `BatchJobs` Lambda function looks like so:

   ```
   import json
   import boto3

   s3 = boto3.client('s3')

   def batch_jobs_handler(event, context):
       return json.loads(s3.get_object(Bucket='YOUR_BUCKET_HERE',
                                       Key=event.get('batch_key'))['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))
   ```
4. Update your workflow to handle the new structure of the output.

   Before implementing this solution, your Map state outputs an array of outputs:

   ```
   [
       {Map_output_1},
       {Map_output_2},
       .
       .
       .
       {Map_output_n}
   ]
   ```

   With this solution, you will now get a list of lists, with each inner list containing the results of each batch:

   ```
   [
       [
           {Batch_1_output_1},
           {Batch_1_output_2},
           .
           .
           .
           {Batch_1_output_n}
       ],
       [
           {Batch_2_output_1},
           {Batch_2_output_2},
           .
           .
           .
           {Batch_2_output_n}
       ],
       .
       .
       .
       [
           {Batch_n_output_1},
           {Batch_n_output_2},
           .
           .
           .
           {Batch_n_output_n}
       ]
   ]
   ```

   Depending on your needs, you may need to adjust some code after the Map in order to handle the new format of the output.

That's it! As long as you set the max batch size correctly, the only way you will hit a payload limit is if your list of S3 keys exceeds the payload limit.

Comment: And what do you do if the list of lists that you return exceed the 256KB? Suppose that your keys are just uuid with the json extension: 256*1024/len(str(uuid.uuid4())+'.json') = 6393 Don't you see possible that a preprocess state can return 6400 items in some use case ?

Comment: This new list of lists could absolutely exceed the 256KB payload limit. You could apply the same pattern I'm describing above in that case though. You would need to batch the list of lists into a list of lists of lists, and another map state/lambda function to process this and pass it along, but it would be the exact same pattern. Just another layer.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a Map State in `Distributed Mode`:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-asl-use-map-state-distributed.html

> Use the Map state in Distributed mode when you need to orchestrate
> large-scale parallel workloads that meet any combination of the
> following conditions:
>
> - The size of your dataset exceeds 256 KB.
> - The workflow's execution event history exceeds 25,000 entries.
> - You need a concurrency of more than 40 parallel iterations.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed workarounds work for specific scenarios, but it is not in the one that the processing of a normal payload can generate a big list of items that can exceed the payload limit.

In a general form I think that the problem can repeat in the scenarios 1->N. I mean when one step might generate many step executions in the workflow.

One of the clear ways to break the complexity of some task is divide it into many others, so this is likely to be needed a lot of times. Also from the scalability perspective, there is a clear advantage in doing that, because the more you break the big computations into little ones there is more granularity and more parallelism and optimizations can be done.

That is what AWS intends to facilitate by [increasing the max payload size](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-larger-state-payloads-for-aws-step-functions/). They call it *dynamic parallelism*.

The problem is that the Map state is the corner-stone of that. Beside the service integrations (database queries, etc.) is the only one that can dynamically derive many tasks from just one step. But there seems to be no way to specify to it that the payload is on a file.

I see a quick solution to the problem would be if they add one optional persistence spec to the each step, for example:

```
stateMachines:
  myStateMachine:
    name: "myStateMachine"
    definition:
      StartAt: preProcess
      States:
        preProcess:
          Type: Task
          Resource:
            Fn::GetAtt: [preProcessLambda, Arn]
          Next: mapState
          ResultPath: "$.preProcessOutput"
          OutputFormat:
             S3:
                Bucket: myBucket
             Compression:
                Format: gzip
        mapState:
          Type: Map
          ItemsPath: "$.preProcessOutput.data"
          InputFormat:
             S3:
                Bucket: myBucket
             Compression:
                Format: gzip
          MaxConcurrency: 100
          Iterator:
            StartAt: doMap
            States:
              doMap:
                Type: Task
                Resource:
                  Fn::GetAtt: [doMapLambda, Arn]
                End: true
          Next: ### next steps, not relevant
```

That way the Map could perform its work even over large payloads.